# View specific virtualhost from within Virtualbox Windows XP?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, localhost, apache-http-server

I currently use `192.168.1.10:85` to refer to my localhost ip address, and I setup port-based virtualhosts because this seems like the only feasible/practical way to view this from within Windows XP on my Debian's VirtualBox.

Is anyone else aware of some advanced techniques in which I could view it by the `ServerName` instead? I would assume I have to hook it up to some sort of DNS server?

I know I can also edit the `hosts` file in my Windows XP and point certain urls to my IP address, but it will always resolve to the primary default virtualhost.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same setup as you do (Debian host, VirtualBox, WinXP guest {plus a Win2k3 server guest}), and IP-based routing works fine without using ports.

Although I did create a hosts file entry in each VM that points to 192.168.56.1, there is no "harm" in doing that since the IP will never change.

Comment: Could you provide details on your vhosts setup?

Comment: Each VM has 2 network adapters enabled. One is "host-only," which allows the VMs to see the host over TCPIP. The other is NAT, which allows the VMs to "share" the host's external network.

Comment: So you had to manually mess with the network adapters? I'll try this out next week.